# Updating Data based on the ID

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, laravel-5

Here is the table data in an array. Fetched from user page

```
 array:5 [▼
 "_token" => "JkmBk6ozJ5NN3TMTobh48EH8MDlsjz7ER98d3mVH"
  "id" => array:2 [▼
   0 => "1"
   1 => "2"
  ]
  "locations" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "13.0717898,77.621292"
    1 => "13.0717898,77.621292"
  ]
  "location" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "Bangalore"
    1 => "Managalore"
  ]
  "submit" => "submit"
  ]
```

I just want to access the array data and Update the table based on the ID

Updation :

I want to replace the locations[0] lat/long value with the location[0]- Bangalore based on the ID

To be specific, I just want to replace all the Lat/long value present in locations array with the place fetched based on the user id.

Please help me with the Controller code.

Here is the code i which i have written to get the table data -

```
 @foreach ($data['Replocationdata'] as $key => $Replocationdata)
                 <tr id="Replocationdata{{$Replocationdata->id}}">
                   <td>{{$Replocationdata->id}}<input type="hidden" 
 name="id[]" value="{{$Replocationdata->id}}" /></td>
                   <td>{{$Replocationdata->locations}}<input type="hidden" 
 name="locations[]" value="{{$Replocationdata->locations}}" /></td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="location[]" /></td>
                 </tr>
 @endforeach
```

And the Controller function

```
public function StorePlacename(Request $request)
{
  foreach ($request as $key => $temp) {
    echo($temp['id']);
  }
}
```

I want to get all these values from blade page (Array values) and access in StorePlacename method.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: To start, you will need a while() loop to iterate through the array. Using that, write some code and post it here if you have any trouble.

Comment: Edited the question. Please take a look into it @ScottSauyet

Comment: Yes. I tried with Iterating using foreach. But not getting how to fetch array values. @EricMPastore

Comment: Your actual data format is not clear.  Can you format it as a plain JS Object or Array (without the arrows or triangles.)  It seems to be an object **and** an array, and that's not how JS works.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values of a form input from laravel view to controller by accessing the input name in your controller like this:

```
$location = $request->input('form_input_name');
```

replace the `form_input_name` with `location` to access the `location` array.